# Do java8 Stream's filter() and map() method use iterations?

Tags: java, java-8, iteration, java-stream

I have a `POJO` in `Person.java` file:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public boolean isAdult() {
        return getAge() >= 18;    
    }
}
```

And then I have a `Demo.java` file which creates a list of persons and uses streams to filter and print content from the list:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = createPeople();
        List<String> names = people.stream()
                                   .filter(person -> person.isAdult())
                                   .map(person -> person.getName())
                                   .collect(toList());
        System.out.println(names);
    }

    private static List<Person> createPeople() {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add("John", 19);
        people.add("Joe", 21);
        people.add("Jill", 16);
        people.add("Sylvester", 18);
        people.add("Hillary", 17);
        people.add("Donald", 4);

        return people;
    }
}
```

I wanted to know:

1> Does `filter()` and `map()` internally use a loop to iterate over all the `Person` objects in the `List` `people`?

2> If yes, do they loop over all the objects in the list two different times (1st iteration by `filter()` and other by `map()`)?

3> If yes again, if I add another `map()` or `filter()` method, will it loop over all the objects again for the third time?

4> If yes again, then how is it different performance wise from our traditional imperative style coding (in-fact, in traditional imperative style, we could do all the filtering and mapping in 1 single loop most of the times. So performance wise, imperative style coding would perform better than streams in such a case.)?

PS: If there is a `No` to any of the above questions, please add an explanation regarding how things work then.

One more: Is there a difference in iteration done by the stream internally and the iteration we do in imperative style? Please shed some more light to my knowledge with some detailed explaination.

Comment: 1>yes, but it iterates over the stream, not the list. 2>no 3>- 4>-

Comment: 2> No? So how does it work. @FrankPuffer

Comment: @FrankPuffer How different is iteration over stream that iteration over a list?

Comment: The list is converted to a stream. It iterates over the stream once and performs `filter`. If the current element passes the filter, it applies `map`.

Comment: @AdityaSingh read the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: @FrankPuffer Then it iterates over the stream again to apply the map? Or simply applies the map to the object that has passed the filter instantaneously?

Comment: @AdityaSingh: Yes, instantaneously. Generally you should not worry too much about performance issues when using streams. they are implemented quite efficiently.

Comment: @FrankPuffer But shouldn't `map()` method's execution start itself after `filter()` method completes execution? I mean, this is the way Java has always worked. How/why does THIS thing happen instantaneously?

Comment: @AdityaSingh: As JB Nizet wrote, the details are explained in the documentation.

Comment: @AdityaSingh: basically, the stream does the equivalent of `List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); for (Person p: people) { if (person.isAdult()) { names.add(person.getName()); } }`. As you see there is no reason to do two passes on the list. A single pass is sufficient.

Comment: @JBNizet Thankyou! I conformed that. But the thing I don't understand is that, that is not how Java worked. As per our traditional Java, 1st `filter()` method should complete the execution.Then `map()` must start executing. I mean, it should have worked like, `List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(); for(Person p : people) {if(p.isAdult()) {persons.add(p);}}` and then `List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); for(Person p : persons) {names.add(p.getName()); }`.  I mean, I just can't digest the fact that it does it in a single loop as you showed. But thanks for your response. I trying more.

Comment: You need to understand that calling stream.filter() doesn't do anything other than adding an intermediate operation to the pipeline. It doesn't do anything with the underlying list. Same for map(). All these operations start executing, as a chain, when the terminal operation (collect() here) is executed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, your code doesn't compile, because `map()` returns a `Stream`, not a `List`. You must end the stream chain with a terminal operation, and both [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) are [intermediate operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). Says so right there in the javadoc. In your case, you need to add `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to make it compile and run ok.

> 1> Does `filter()` and `map()` internally use a loop to iterate over all the `Person` objects in the `List` people?

No. The terminal operation is doing the looping.

Since questions 2 to 4 assumes a `Yes` answer, they have no answer.

> If there is a `No` to any of the above questions, please add an explanation regarding how things work then.

Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description), or search the web. It's pretty well explained.

> Is there a difference in iteration done by the stream internally and the iteration we do in imperative style?

Yes, e.g. streams can utilize parallel thread execution. Even single-threaded there is a difference in how the entire operation works, though logically, at a high level, they are essentially the same.

---

**Example**

In your code, with the `collect()` call added, the equivalent imperative code would be:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person person : people)
    if (person.isAdult())
        names.add(person.getName());
```

To compare to what the stream logic does, first you define the lambdas passed to `filter()` and `map()`:

```
Predicate<Person>        filter = person -> person.isAdult();
Function<Person, String> map    = person -> person.getName();
```

Then you get the `Collector` by calling `Collectors.toList()`, and retrieve the objects it provide:

```
Collector<String, List<String>, List<String>> collector = (Collector) Collectors.toList();
Supplier<List<String>>               supplier    = collector.supplier();
BiConsumer<List<String>, String>     accumulator = collector.accumulator();
Function<List<String>, List<String>> finisher    = collector.finisher();
```

Now, the `stream()` call basically provides an `Iterator` (it's actually a `Spliterator`) and the `collect` call will iterate, so combined they are equivalent to the `for` loop. I won't cover the full logic of how `Stream`, `Spliterator` and `collect()` works. Search the web if you need more detail on that.

So, the imperative `for` loop above becomes:

```
List<String> list = supplier.get();        // list = new ArrayList<>()
for (Person person : people)               // collect() loop using Spliterator from stream()
    if (filter.test(person)) {             // if (person.isAdult())
        String value = map.apply(person);  // value = person.getName()
        accumulator.accept(list, value);   // list.add(value)
    }
List<String> names = finisher.apply(list); // names = list
```

Comment: Pretty well explained. Thanks a lot. I added the `collect()` call to avoid confusion to further readers.